# change color of data-icon of selectpicker option in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap Selectpicker and i want to change the color of data-icon of options in select. each data-icon has specific color and I have to use internal CSS for it anybody can help me please how can i do that?

```
<select class="bs-select selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="true" multiple>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle">Mustard</option>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle">Ketchup</option>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle">Relish</option>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle">Mayonnaise</option>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle">Barbecue Sauce</option>
</select>
```

[image: the circles are data-icon]

Comment: Can you please add fiddle or any other code example to see these data-icons how are visualized into options?

Comment: i add a picture of that, the circles are data-icon

Comment: We need the code, because beside <option data-icon="fa fa-circle">Mustard</option>, bootstrap outputs additional tags.

Comment: I found that the icon is outputed as <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-name"></span>, so you can just change the color of the icon, like .glyphicon-name{color: red;}

Comment: in html file i just use option and data-icon and the values of options are come from database and the color of each data-icon is specific , because of that i have to use inline css in option tag how can i do that?

Comment: To add inline css you can make following: <option data-icon="fa fa-circle" style="color: red;">Mustard</option>, but in this case maybe this will change only the color of the text.

The html I show you is not in your file, but generated by loading the page. If you inspect the page, you will see the additional tags. That's why my first suggestion was just to add classes to every single option and then: .option-class .glyphicon-name{color: red;}

Comment: data-icon is font icon and the color will be change with this code but the value of option will be change too, and i dont want this. I know but it will generate automatically and i cant change the color without loading page

Comment: Okay, so inline css is not the solutuon. I see here:https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#icons. Please inspect the select option and you will see the glyphicon tag.

Answer (score 4):

From [Custom content](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#custom-content)

I use `<option data-content="<i class='fa fa-circle red'></i> Mustard">Mustard</option>` as option to select

see `data-content="<i class='fa fa-circle red'></i> Mustard"` Added class `red` to it which changes color of data-icon  not the text of option

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('select').selectpicker();

}); //]]>
```

```css
.green {
  color: green !important
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow !important
}

.white {
  color: white !important
}

.blue {
  color: blue !important
}

.red {
  color: red !important
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group:not(.input-group-btn),
.bootstrap-select.btn-group[class*="span"] {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="bs-select selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="true" multiple>
    <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-circle red'></i> Mustard">Mustard</option>
    <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-circle blue'></i> Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
    <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-circle green'></i> Relish">Relish</option>
    <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-circle yellow'></i> Mayonnaise">Mayonnaise</option>
    <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-circle white'></i> Barbecue Sauce">Barbecue Sauce</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, just add some color classes and then style them:

```
<select class="bs-select selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="true" multiple>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle" class="red">Mustard</option>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle" class="blue">Ketchup</option>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle" class="green">Relish</option>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle" class="yellow">Mayonnaise</option>
    <option data-icon="fa fa-circle" class="white">Barbecue Sauce</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.red {color: red};
.blue {color: blue};
.green {color: green};
.yellow {color: yellow};
.white {color: white};
```

Comment: as i mentioned in my question i want to change the color of data-icon only (not value of option) . and because colores are dynamic and come from database i need to add inline css